# Newly created G Suite domains are subject to the consumer limit

Tags: google-apps-script

My online registration script - which is sending emails to reduce in person contacts - is reaching the quotas for Google Services.

Is there a way to expedite the limit on a newly created account?

Comment: Is it a paid or unpaid domain?

Comment: Usually the limit is applied at least for the first billing cycle. But as a GSuite customer you are entitled to [Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en&ref_topic=7067151). Contact the support team and see if they can do something to hrlp you.